# font awesome icons broken

Tags: font-awesome

I am using font awesome on my JSP project, I am using the following import:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

The icons are showing up as square boxes, here is a example:
[Its a little hard to see but you can still see the boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fezY3.png)

Thanks for reading, any assistance is appreciated.

(Using Apache Tomcat 9)

Comment: how is this even closely java related? Just because you use Java in your project,d doesn't make this a java issue

Comment: @Stultuske my fault, sorry. </3

Comment: You need to provide more information on your code. The import itself is fine, how do you define the icon and what styling do you set around it, that my interfere? Which software did you try? Maybe just a rendering issue in your browser.

Comment: @user1438038 here is my usage of it - 

```html
<i class="metismenu-icon fa fa-home"></i>
```

Comment: the other style alongside it is ```.metismenu-icon{opacity:.6}```

Comment: @DeqnessHosting: Works for me. Did you alter any font on a higher level? Did you check with another browser? Sometimes browsers fail to render font-awesome icons when loading a page. Usually reloading the page fixes that issue.

Comment: @user1438038 I will give it a try on another browser etc.

Comment: I tried in two different browsers, nothing changed, even tried on some online browsers like browserling

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of your code that reproduces the problem? We will not get any further, unless you provide more information.

Comment: @user1438038 I do not understand, anything you need me to show you I happily will, just ask me for it.